# Расчёты в HTML-документах

Tags: html

На сайте есть рецептуры блюд с указанием количества продуктов (грамм, штук) на порцию. Как организовать по запросу посетителя перерасчет на любое количество порций, не создавая базу данных? Владею только HTML. Благодарю отозвавшихся быстро.

Comment: про JavaScript не слышали?

Answer (score 2):

Если брать простейший вариант, то с использованием JavaScript (JQuery) должно получится что-то такое:

HTML:

```
Молоко <span id='i1'>200</span><br />
Масло <span id='i2'>100</span><br />
Мука <span id='i3'>150</span><br />
Количество порций: <input type="text" id="num" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Рассчитать" />
<div id="total" style="display:none;">
Итого:
Молоко <span id='t1'></span><br />
Масло <span id='t2'></span><br />
Мука <span id='t3'></span><br />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('calc').onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('i1').innerHTML * document.getElementById('num').value;
    document.getElementById('t2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('i2').innerHTML * document.getElementById('num').value;
    document.getElementById('t3').innerHTML = document.getElementById('i3').innerHTML * document.getElementById('num').value;
    document.getElementById('total').style.display="block";;
};
```

JQuery:

```
$('#calc').click(function(){
    $('#t1').text($('#i1').text()*$('#num').val());
    $('#t2').text($('#i2').text()*$('#num').val());
    $('#t3').text($('#i3').text()*$('#num').val());
    $('#total').show();
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJpAJ/)

Comment: Ну и на кой тут jQuery?

Comment: для большей наглядности и простоты восприятия.

Comment: ну как же без [неё](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: ребята, скриншот просто бомба, я своим на работе всем показал, спасибо

Comment: @Spectre - четко :DDD

Comment: Ну вот запинали))) Хоть бы уже заплюсовали как на скриншоте, а то... :(

Comment: Отдельное спасибо @Spectre за скрин!))) Супер! :D

Comment: Я - резиг-хейтер, могу только минуснуть :(